# I need help looping through a JSON file with php

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, foreach

I have [this JSON file](http://toddbenrud.com/jsonFiles/wqu4-27-17_editCopy.json) (shortened version) and need to loop through it for each question# and add the question details to a MySQL DB. There are 10 questions per quiz. Each quiz consists of a url, title, image, and questions(array). There are 10 questions with 4 answer options for each quiz.

I'm looking for a starting point so I can begin to loop through and echo the questions. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Hand Code Data Extraction - I want to loop through this.**

```
// this will be associated with every question in a quiz.
    $url = $json['rows'][0]['URL'];
    $Title = $json['rows'][0]['Title'];
    $Questions = $json['rows'][0]['Questions'];
    $Image = $json['rows'][0]['Image'];
//  I need these to loop thorugh for Q1, Q2, Q3, etc..... for every Q# in row0
    $Q1Text = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question1']['Question Text'];
    $Q1MediaURL = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question1']['Question Media']['Media url'];
    $Q1MediaType = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question1']['Question Media']['Media Type'];
    $Q1Answer1 = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question1']['Answers']['Answer1']['Answer'];
    $Q1Answer1Value = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question1']['Answers']['Answer1']['Value'];
    $Q1Answer2 = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question1']['Answers']['Answer2']['Answer'];
    $Q1Answer2Value = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question1']['Answers']['Answer2']['Value'];
    $Q1Answer3 = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question1']['Answers']['Answer3']['Answer'];
    $Q1Answer3Value = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question1']['Answers']['Answer3']['Value'];
    $Q1Answer4 = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question1']['Answers']['Answer4']['Answer'];
    $Q1Answer4Value = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question1']['Answers']['Answer4']['Value'];

    $Q2Text = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question2']['Question Text'];
    $Q2MediaURL = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question2']['Question Media']['Media url'];
    $Q2MediaType = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question2']['Question Media']['Media Type'];
    $Q2Answer1 = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question2']['Answers']['Answer1']['Answer'];
    $Q2Answer1Value = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question2']['Answers']['Answer1']['Value'];
    $Q2Answer2 = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question2']['Answers']['Answer2']['Answer'];
    $Q2Answer2Value = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question2']['Answers']['Answer2']['Value'];
    $Q2Answer3 = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question2']['Answers']['Answer3']['Answer'];
    $Q2Answer3Value = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question2']['Answers']['Answer3']['Value'];
    $Q2Answer4 = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question2']['Answers']['Answer4']['Answer'];
    $Q2Answer4Value = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question2']['Answers']['Answer4']['Value'];

    $Q3Text = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question3']['Question Text'];
    $Q3MediaURL = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question3']['Question Media']['Media url'];
    $Q3MediaType = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question3']['Question Media']['Media Type'];
    $Q3Answer1 = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question3']['Answers']['Answer1']['Answer'];
    $Q3Answer1Value = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question3']['Answers']['Answer1']['Value'];
    $Q3Answer2 = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question3']['Answers']['Answer2']['Answer'];
    $Q3Answer2Value = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question3']['Answers']['Answer2']['Value'];
    $Q3Answer3 = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question3']['Answers']['Answer3']['Answer'];
    $Q3Answer3Value = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question3']['Answers']['Answer3']['Value'];
    $Q3Answer4 = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question3']['Answers']['Answer4']['Answer'];
    $Q3Answer4Value = $json['rows'][0]['Questions']['Question3']['Answers']['Answer4']['Value'];
```

**UPDATE: This is the working code I ended up with. Thanks for your help @Lou!**

```
foreach($json['rows'] as $row){ // This will loop trough every rows in your array.
    foreach($row['Questions'] as $question){ //This will loop trough all the questions of the current row.
        echo ''.print_r($question).'<br>'; //You can access the array of your question here. using $question. For now it will just print it's content.

        echo "<strong>Quiz URL:</strong> " . $row["URL"]. "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Quiz Title:</strong> " . $row["Title"]. "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Quiz Image:</strong> " . $row["Image"]. "<br><br><br>";


        echo "<strong>Question Text:</strong> " . $question['Question Text']. "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Media URL:</strong> " . $question['Question Media']['Media url']. "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Media Type:</strong> " . $question['Question Media']['Media Type']. "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Answer1:</strong> " . $question['Answers']['Answer1']['Answer'] . " | " . $question['Answers']['Answer1']['Value'] . "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Answer2:</strong> " . $question['Answers']['Answer2']['Answer'] . " | " . $question['Answers']['Answer2']['Value'] . "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Answer3:</strong> " . $question['Answers']['Answer3']['Answer'] . " | " . $question['Answers']['Answer3']['Value'] . "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Answer4:</strong> " . $question['Answers']['Answer4']['Answer'] . " | " . $question['Answers']['Answer4']['Value'] . "<br>";


        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to write code for you. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks for taking a look at my question and responding. I understand that SO isn't here to write code and I'm not looking for copy/paste code here. I simply looking for a "starting point" for my loop. I've written the code above and I'm looking for guidance to transform that into a loop for each question. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I assume, by looking at your current code, that you already decoded your json as an array.

Now if you want to loop trough that array. You may want to use foreach loops. See the snippet below if it can help you :

```
foreach($json['rows'] as $row){ // This will loop trough every rows in your array.
    foreach($row['Questions'] as $question){ //This will loop trough all the questions of the current row.
        echo '<pre>'.print_r($question).'</pre><br><br>'; //You can access the array of your question here. using $question. For now it will just print it's content.
    }
}
```

If you need further help, let me know.

Comment: do you know why it adds a `1` to the end of each print?